# Bitmap crashes with "Cannot generate texture from the bitmap" message

Tags: java, android, bitmap, recycle

I work on simple app with animation. I use standard View. In onDraw metod my app paints background (stored as a Bitmap) and a couple of sprites. In the main loop I need to modify the background bitmap (code attached). I use for that setPixel() metod. 
From time to time when I try to change bitmap I receive in the LogCat such message: "Cannot generate texture from the bitmap". After that bacground still appears on the screen but I can't use neither getPixel() nor setPixel() methods. I found some hint that it is because bitmap was recycled but I added some controls in my app and after this "crash" bitmap.isRecycled() is still false and bitmap.isMutable() is still true. So, I have no idea what's the problem.

```
public void drawOnBmp (float xF, float yF, float r) {       
    float[][] kolo;
    float xP, yP;
    float xStart, yStart;

    xStart = xF - r / 2;
    yStart = yF - r / 2;
    kolo = new float[(int)r + 1][(int)r + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
        xP = r / 2 + (float)(r / 2 * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * (double)i / 360));
        yP = r / 2 + (float)(r / 2 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * (double)i / 360));
        kolo[(int)xP][(int)yP] = 1;
    }
    boolean start;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)r + 1; i++) {
        start = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)r + 1; j++) {
            if (kolo[i][j] == 1)
                if (start == false) start = true;
                else if (j >= r / 2) break;
            if (start == true) kolo[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
    // obraz is a bitmap with background
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)r; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)r; j++) {
            if(kolo[i][j] == 1 && (int)xStart + i >= 0 && (int)yStart + j >= 0 && 
               (int)xStart + i < obraz.getWidth() && (int)yStart + j < obraz.getHeight())
                obraz.setPixel((int)xStart + i, (int)yStart + j, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem. Didn't solve it yet but this may be usefull for anybody.

Some hints are coming from [google.group's](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Android-developers/uh4UpvN_Be8) thread

> What's interesting is that it seems to be related to the Hardware
>   rendering introduced with Android 3.x. Setting the layer type to
>   software for the respective View that does the drawing of the bitmap,
>   fixes the issue.

So setting

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

really worked for me, but in my app it impacted performance so I have to use`View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE`

I'm still looking for the solution and roots of the issue. Will update if found any. Also any additional information appreciated.